# How to stop html network from downloading the same images?

Tags: html, networking, request-headers, response-headers

This is my game: https://colonist.io/

In the game there is the chat section, which show who has rolled what dice & gained what resource written in HTML.

[image]

So whenever a dice is rolled around 10 images are printed. Each of these images do a network call. I would normally expect the network call to not download the same image but for some reason it does and I can't find a way to make the browser use it from cache.

The [response headers](https://prnt.sc/pph8rt) are set to: `public, max-age=14400`
The [request headers](https://prnt.sc/pph8rt) are set to: `cache-control: no-cache`

So I am guessing the problem has got to do with the request headers but I couldn't find a way to change it.

How can I make it so that when I print a new HTML `<img src="../dist/images/card_lumber.svg?v56">` it doesn't do an extra network call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a hunch, but make sure you've deselected the `disable cache` button in the network tab of the chrome developer tools.:

[image]

Comment: Wow it works. Silly me. I'll accept your answer. Thanks